# map string and vector, how to use find

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have to generate a vector of vectors starting from a word.

Hereafter I have put a minimal example, with one letter (although later I should use longer words), of what I need to do.
Unfortunately, I don't understand how the function "find" should work for the map and I get a compiling error.  Any help, please?

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector <vector <double> > assign_mat(string &s, map<string, vector<double> > &amatr){
  vector <vector <double> > res;

  for(size_t i=0; i<s.size(); ++i){
    res.push_back(amatr.find(s[i])->second)  ;

  }

  return res;
}


int main(){

map<string, vector<double> > amm_vals =     {
{"S", {-0.228,1.399,-4.760,0.670,-2.647} },
{"T", {-0.032,0.326,2.213,0.908,1.313} },
{"V", {-1.337,-0.279,-0.544,1.242,-1.262} }
                            };

string s="V";
vector <vector <double> > ares;

ares=assign_mat(s, amm_vals);
return 0;
}
```

The error I get is the following:

> In function ‘`std::vector<std::vector<double> > assign_mat(std::__cxx11::string&, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::vector<double> >&)`’:
>   main_code.cpp:15:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘`std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::vector<double> >::find(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char> >::value_type&)`’
>   `res.push_back(amatr.find(s[i])->second)  ;`

Comment: `s[i]` is a `char`, obviously. You're passing a single, lonely, `char` to `find()`. Since the map's key is a `std::string`, `find()`'s parameter must be a `std::string`, and not a `char`. Furthermore, if the `char` does not exist, `find()` returns `end()`. If you try to access its `second`, hillarity ensues. You must fix both bugs.

Comment: 1) Please copy-paste the entire error message. 2) `s[i]` is of type `char`, and your map has `std::string` as a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to add all values from `amm_vals` which have keys which are equal to a single character of `s`? If so, then you can convert `s[i]` to a string by concatenating it to an empty string.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> assign_mat(const std::string &s, std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>> &amatr){
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> res;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i ) {
        std::string _s = s[i] + std::string{}; // or std::string _s( 1, s[i] );
        auto _where = amatr.find( _s );
        if ( _where != amatr.end() )
            res.push_back( _where->second );
    }

  return res;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Although now the code compiles, if I pass the value "V" I expect a vector of vectors with one vector inside.  Such vector should be: {-1.337,-0.279,-0.544,1.242,-1.262} but ares seems empty.

Comment: @Fabrizio are you sure that your iterate the corret way for `ares` because this solution is fine

Comment: @Mandy007, I had a `to_string( s[i] )` which wouldn't work. I've updated it to make it work.

Comment: @Mandy007, not according to the standard. It'll compile because it treats the `char` as an `int`, but then you don't get a `"V"`, you get `"86"`

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the recommendations of @SamVarshavchik  your code should look like:

```
 vector <vector <double> > assign_mat(string &s, map<string, vector<double> > &amatr){
     vector <vector <double> > res;
     for(size_t i=0; i<s.size(); ++i){
         if(amatr.find(string(1, s[i])) != amatr.end())
             res.push_back(amatr[string(1, s[i])]);
     }
     return res;
}
```

But I think it is better to use the following idea:

```
vector <vector <double> > assign_mat(vector<string> &s, map<string, vector<double> > &amatr){
    vector <vector <double> > res;
    for(size_t i=0; i<s.size(); ++i){
        if(amatr.find(s[i]) != amatr.end())
            res.push_back(amatr[s[i]]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

And remember that the `find` in std library returns an iterator to the first element in the range [first,last) that compares equal to val. If no such element is found, the function returns last.

Comment: `string(s[i])` isn't valid. You can do `string(1, s[i])`. `amatr[s[i]]` is also invalid.